# Create a button in AlertManager plugin for Mattermost

Tags: go, prometheus-alertmanager, mattermost, custom-code

I am using alertmanager plugin to send aletrs from prometheus.

I need to add a button in this file https://github.com/cpanato/mattermost-plugin-alertmanager/blob/main/server/webhook.go, which will be visible in case of successful firing status.

Button will execute script from url after clicking it.

Please contact me if anyone made similar implementation, and could point me to a solution?